# Energy of RLC circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electric-circuits, oscillators

If you are given a general differential equation for an RLC circuit, for example,
$$L\left(\frac{d^2 Q}{dt^2}\right) + R\left(\frac{dQ}{dt}\right) + \frac QC = V\cos(\omega t),$$
which is a driven circuit, how would you find the average stored energy?

I believe the formula is $E=RI^2$. I solved for the amplitude $A$ by using the general solution $Q=Ae^{i\omega t}$, but I am unsure how to proceed with the energy by solving the differential equation.

Comment: I think what you wrote there, $E=RI^2$, is from power $P = IV$, which for a resistor is $P=I(IR)=RI^2$.  But this is power (energy per time) expended in the resistor, what you want is the stored energy in the circuit.  Energy can be stored in a capacitor ($U_{C}=\frac{1}{2}Q^2/C$) and can be stored in an inductor ($U_{L}=\frac{1}{2}LI^2$). Since you already did the hard part (solving the differential equation for $Q$), just add the energy stored in these two components and average over time.

Comment: @John That should really be posted as an answer. I was going to post the same thing but then noticed you had it here. Don't want to shamelessly steal your credit :)

Comment: @jkeuhlen I didn't calculate the actual answer, so considered it a comment.  I'm never sure how much to help versus show with these homework type questions.